# ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker css not being applied properly

Tags: angular, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Got the ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker into my project, but I don't think the CSS is being applied properly and I'm not sure why. This is what it looks like now, vs what it SHOULD look like...

[image]

In my component I use:

```
styleUrls: ['../../../css/bootstrap.min.css',
            '../../../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css']
```

and I have those files in-place copied from a cdn.

It seems that "bootstrap.min.css" is working, because when I remove it the calendar won't open at all, but if I remove "bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" than it looks EXACTLY the same, so I think the problem is there.

HTML:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                    a2e-datetimepicker
                    [date]="date"
                    [options]="a2eOptions"
                    (onChange)="dateChange($event)"
                    (onClick)="dateClick()"
                    />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Class:

```
export class DateTimePicker implements OnInit {

  date: moment.Moment;
  a2eOptions: any;

  dateChange(date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  dateClick() {
    console.log('click click!')
  }

  getTime() {
    alert('Selected time is:' + this.date);
  };

  addTime(val, selector) {
    this.date = moment(this.date.add(val, selector));
  };

  clearTime() {
    this.date = null;
  };

  constructor(){
      this.date = moment();
      this.a2eOptions = {format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'};
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(datetimepicker);
  }

}
```

Not getting any errors.

UPDATE:

I want to keep the stypes in this component only. Tried doing this, but it leaked out and ruins the page of any component that includes it.

```
styles: ['
    @import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    @import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css";
']
```

Comment: try removing your css styleurl for it, and just add the cdn in you index.html and just see what happens. here it is if you dont have it   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">`

Comment: Nailed it again Bean! Make it an answer and I'll check it. I think I have it working now and can finally move on hahah.

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the styleUrl for your date picker and just add the cdn to your index.html file. here is the cdn

`href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepick‌​er/4.17.43/build/css‌​/bootstrap-datetimep‌​icker.min.css">`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize putting it in the index.html ruined other components. So I tried keeping local, and now it seems the css is leaking out... any thoughts on that one? :0